# RallyRestAPI Create Build with ChangeSets

Tags: rally

I am creating Rally Build Records as part of a TeamCity to Rally integration but havving issues associating a Build with a ChangeSet.

I find a set of related ChangeSets that match a particular criteria and have them in an array of String. I then create a JsonArray object, add these "_ref" strings as JsonPrimatives into the Array, add the array to my create Json object and add it to Rally.

However, what happens is that the build is created but the result has an empty Changeset array.

I have tried including the changesets in the createRequest and also doing an updateRequest but in both cases the response is SUCCESS, there are no errors or warnings reported and the Changeset array is returned as null and re-querying shows all other data as expected but the changeSet array is empty.

Here is the code.

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.addProperty("Workspace", def.getWorkspace().getRef());
obj.addProperty("Duration",1.05);
obj.addProperty("Message", "Master 4683 Success");
obj.addProperty("Start", isoFormat.format(new Date()));
obj.addProperty("Status","SUCCESS");
obj.addProperty("Number","4683");
obj.addProperty("Uri", "http://");
obj.addProperty("BuildDefinition",def.getRef());

// changeSets is a ArrayList<String> of "_ref" strings of VALID changesets references. 
if (changeSets != null && changeSets.size() > 0) {
    JsonArray changeSetList = new JsonArray();
    for (String id : changeSets) {
        changeSetList.add(new JsonPrimitive(id));
    }
    obj.add("Changesets", changeSetList);
}

String ref = connector.Create("Build",obj);
connector.Delete(ref, null);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is that instead of populating your JsonArray with JsonPrimitive's having just the value of the ref, you actually need a JsonObject with a key/value pair of {"_ref", "/changeset/12345678910.js"}. I.E. make a change similar to the following:

```
// changeSets is a ArrayList<String> of "_ref" strings of VALID changesets references. 
if (changeSets != null && changeSets.size() > 0) {
    JsonArray changeSetList = new JsonArray();
    for (String id : changeSets) {
        JsonObject thisChangeset = new JsonObject();
        thisChangeset.addProperty("_ref", id);
        changeSetList.add(thisChangeset);
    }
    obj.add("Changesets", changeSetList);
}
```

And I believe your code should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

I Used JSonPrimative as the JSon library does not allow a string to be added to a JsonArray. It needs to be a JSonPrimative to do this. 

I tried as you suggested above and added a JsonObject (Key/Value Pairs) to the JSonArray and adding the JSonArray to the object to be created but it causes an error from the API call with the text "Constraint Violation: Constraint Violation". 

I know when I created similar links in my C# importer (TestSteps attached to TestCases) I just added an array of references as strings and not as JsonObjects (Key/Value pair).

Comment: The example in my answer contained a typo - it should have said `addProperty` rather than `setProperty`, but I'm sure you discovered that. I've edited the answer to update. The key/value pair of the JsonObject will be needed as the serializer will expect to have a "_ref" attribute. The complaint about the Constraint Violation likely means that there's something illegal about the nature of the request itself on the Rally server side (i.e. missing/invalid required field, for example).

Comment: Examining the full Errors and Warnings Collection from the CreateRequest might provide better data on the nature of the constraint issue. I know the JsonObject with the Changeset ref key/value pair works as I've successfully tested it, and ended up with a new Build in Rally with associated Changesets. You can find my working example code here: https://gist.github.com/markwilliams970/5511534

Comment: Thanks mark, I will take another look at your example. I did examine the full error response from the create command and the only information was the text as above.

Comment: Thanks Mark, found the issue. I had a duplicate reference in my list which caused the issue. The ChangeSet list must have unique values (which makes sense). Unfortunately the error response wasn't particularly helpful, but you were.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the issue! I concur the error message is too broad to be very useful. Nice work troubleshooting!

Comment: And just to be clear, your solution was the correct one. This differs from the .net API library where TestSteps are just an JsonArray of Strings not an array of Key/Value Pair objects as required in Java. The TeamCity-->Rally Integrator is now 100% operational in our environment and I have made the code OpenSource on GitHub for any other organisation that wants to do this. Thank you for all your assistance through this.

Comment: Glad things are working. Thanks so much for sharing your efforts through Github! I'm sure other Rally customers will benefit.